# How to migrate posts from Craft CMS to Wordpress?

Tags: database, wordpress, migrate, craftcms

I have about 160 posts on a Craft CMS site that I need to migrate to a new Wordpress build. Whats the easiest way to do this? Surprisingly not seeing much info on this.

Comment: Get the data from Craft CMS using any export plugin (into XML, CSV,...), or query them directly from the database, and then import it using any WordPress import plugin (e.g. WP All Import).

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a plugin, export the posts via the admin panel, direct DB access or use something like GraphQL or element-api (API's) to get the data you need.

There's plenty of ways to do it, just depends on your skill and tools you have available.

The reason there's not much information out there on this topic is because usually people are trying to do the opposite.